# Temperature and Moisture indices in Geomorphometry and Gradient metrices toolbox

Tags: arcgis-desktop, terrain, modelling

I have generated various temperature and moisture indices using toolbox in arcgis. But HLI output is showing values more than 1. values should be between 0 and 1. similarly IMI values should be between 0 and 100, but i am getting much higher values. What may be the reason?
Is there any need to do focal mean of these outputs using 3*3 windows?

Comment: What latitude is your analysis? There was an error in the McCune equation for southern latitudes. Because of this we removed the model associated with data south of the equator until we could sort things out. We do have a fix which will be released in the next version.

Comment: My latitude is in northern hemisphere only (32 degree north). I used version 2.0 of your toolbox. HLI and IMI are under temperture and moisture indices menu. In this only input and output options are there. whereas in Surface texture menu for landform and all others, neighborhood settings are there (default 3*3). i want to know whether the same 3*3 window is used deault in HLI and IMI.

Comment: I calculated IMI using equation in raster calc. used eqn is IMI=(hillshade.0.5) + (curvature . 0.15)+(flow accumulation . 0.35). here also values are coming similar ranging from 77 to 18590. whether any normalization or rescaling of hill shade, curvature and flow accumulation is required

Comment: I think in  toolbox the calculation is done without rescaling of hillshade, curvature and flow accumulation between 0 to 100 and inversion of curvature.(as per Iversen, 1997). i did rescaling of these three between 0 and 100 and then used the above equation, I am getting values between 0 and 100. i feel you missed the rescaling step in tool. Please let me now if i did it correctly or not?

Answer (score 1):

First, the HLI is derived using slope and aspect so, there is no focal window used in the function, just the standard polynomial used to fit the slope direction and angle. Please, keep in mind that the equation is based on a non-parametric regression. Because of this, there is a theoretical range but it is not necessarily bounded. If there are values in the DEM that act as outliers, then the metric may exhibit outlier ranges as well. I am not sure where the focal analysis idea came from but I would recommend against it. Because of the incorporated directionality, this is not a metric that it makes sense to smooth.

Second, IMI scales the variables used in the metric but this does not represent proportions/percentages, as being intimated. The scaling is just used to make the metric standardized and could represent any range. The IMI is relative no matter how scaled. However, if you standardize, there is absolutely no was to compare across study areas. So, if you have proximal areas that are not contiguous, the metric becomes statistically irrelevant. I have discussed this with Louis Iverson and he agrees with not standardizing when using the metric in replicated designs. It was a conscious decision to not standardize IMI although, I could add scaling as an option.

Neither of these models allows for the specification of a window/neighborhood size. Given the temporary rasters needed (ie., slope, aspect, flow accumulation, curvature, hillshade), it is just not a relevant argument. I do have to say, I have no idea to what you are referring to in your comment "inversion of curvature" in reference to IMI. This is not detailed in the Iverson *et al*., (1997) paper and Louis has never mentioned it in discussing derivation of the metric. The IMI is just a weighted overlay and inverting curvature does not make much sense.

Comment: Thank you for nicely explaining things to me. The idea of "inversion of curvature" cam e to me from a publication by Kirk W Davies et al in Rangeland Ecology & Management 63: 630-637. (Estimating Juniper cover from NAIP imagery and evaluating relationships between potential cover and environmental variable, pg. 633). The idea of focal analysis was to smoothen the output using a low pass filter (3*3), to remove any ubrupt values.Is it correct to use the index outputs as such without any smoothing/filtering? I have seen some people smoothing the outputs before further analysis.

Comment: I would not recommend "smoothing" HLI however, since IMI uses flow accumulation in its derivation, and the D8 algorithm is notorious for flow artifacts, a smoothing function would be quite warranted as it is with CTI. If I have adequately addressed your questions please mark as answered.